# C# - CryptographicException was unhandled

Tags: c#, cryptography

I have been having trouble with the following code for a few days now and I really do not know why it is that i'm having so much trouble with it, was hoping someone could point me to the right direction, perhaps i'm overthinking it.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

Additional information: Bad Data.

This is the code

```
return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider() { Key = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key)), Mode = CipherMode.ECB, Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7 }.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(encrypted.Split('-').Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16)).ToArray(), 0, encrypted.Split('-').Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16)).ToArray().Length));
```

This is what is calling it.

```
{
        if (args.Length == 0)
            return;

        if (args[0] == "new")
            File.Delete("old_updater.exe");
        else if (args[0] != Encryption.Decrypt_Param("06-8A-AB-DD-64-4C-6D-ED-AD-83-4A-1E-80-E4-36-15", "Incompitis Ingoramous"))
            Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();

        if (Process.GetProcessesByName("Updater").Length > 1)
            Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
```

Comment: Crypto is hard enough without trying to make it a one liner. Please clean up your code before posting, and test the intermediate values. I would strongly suggest you are *underdoing* it instead of *overdoing* it.

Answer (score 0):

Breaking the code down helps!

The error that you're getting is in the TransformFinalBlock.  Your encrpyted data in your example code does not appear to be padded.

Change the padding to `PaddingMode.None` and it no longer throws an error.